# Pass Multiple arguments to a function using array or arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a working function which takes some parameters (either integers or strings) and performs certain operation. Please see the example in its very basic form:

```
var myFunc = function(a,b,c){
    return a * b * c;
}
function(1,2,3);
```

This function is used to work with large amounts or data and instead or running the function as shown below:

```
function(1,2,3);
function(2,3,4);
function(5,8,7);
function(8,9,0);
function(5,3,2);
...
```

I would like to find a way to pass an array of array (or objects) and run the function only once with the data from the array.

I started to work on the algorithm but cannot figure it out. Could you please take a look to the code below and suggest it's completion?

```
var myFunc = function(arr){
  arr.forEach(function(item, index){
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
        // some magic
    }
  })
}
myFunc([[5,7,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,9]]);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you supposed to return `[105, 24, 54]`?

Comment: no, it should run multiple times and each time return only values from each array. 
Example:
myFunc([[5,7,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,9]]); //returns: 
1)  105 
2)  24
4)  54

Comment: What? A function can only return once... what you want is what I described

Answer (score 1):

You should use **arguments** instead of **arr**

```
var myFunc = function(){
  arguments.forEach(function(item, index){
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
        // some magic
    }
  })
}
myFunc([5,7,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,9]);
```

Comment: I've just also thought about this, and can get rid of one array main arr. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please remove **[ ]** look like my code ... and recheck

Comment: `[...arguments]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will multiply each set of arrays and return an array of the products (105,24,54).

```
var myFunc = function(arr){
  var products = new Array();
  arr.forEach(function(item, index){
    var subtotal = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
        // some magic
        subtotal *= item[i];
    }
    products[index] = subtotal;
  });
  return products;
}
myFunc([[5,7,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,9]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the outer array, reduce the inner arrays by multiplying the consecutive numbers.

```js
const myFunc = arr => arr.map(xs => xs.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1))

console.log(
  myFunc([[5,7,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,9]])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you read this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

```
let myFunc = (...args) => {
      let result = 1;
      for (let i in args) {
         result = result * args[i];
      } 
      return result;
    };
console.log(myFunc(2,2,3))
```